# Stop replacing occurrence in subsequent lines when occurrence is found in one line

Tags: substitute

I understood that

```
:%s/foo/bar
```

replaces the first occurrence of 'foo' with 'bar' in each line and repeats the process for all lines.

My requirement is to stop skimming through lines after the replace is done in the first line where the match is found.

Please help me with this

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
:%s/foo/bar/c
```

This will ask you to confirm that you want to make the substitution for every
match, so you could accept the first with `y` and then press `q` to quit.

Another way that would free you from the need to interact with the confirmation
interface would be:

```
:/foo/s/foo/bar
```

Here the first `/foo/` is used as a line address (see `:help 10.3` and `:help cmdline-ranges`) on which to apply subsequent commands. In this case the
subsequent command is the `s/foo/bar`, so it only happens on the first line on
which a match is found.